# Android studio, assembleDebugTest cause Multiple dex files define

Tags: unit-testing, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

trying to run android tests in android studio 0.8.1

I can run assembleDebug and assembleTest properly. But when I try to run the android test it calles assembleDebug and assembleDebugTest and with the latter I get the problem with 'Multiple dex files define'

a few pictures:

[image]
[image]
[image]

and the build.gradle of the project

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':libraries:someLib')
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.+')
    compile ('fr.avianey:facebook-android-api:+@aar')
    compile ('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.3.1')
    compile ('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.3.1')
    compile ('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.3.0')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

    //androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'
    //androidTestCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.1.+'
    //androidTestCompile 'com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.+'
    //androidTestCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.5.1'
}
```

and the build.gradle of the "someLib"

```
dependencies {
    compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.+')
    compile ('com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0')
    compile (group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '16.0-rc1')
}
```

they both share the rest

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So far I tried 2 solutions that seems to work but I am pretty sure there has to be something better.

Anyway 1 solution:

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { theTask ->
    if("assembleDebugTest".toString().equals(theTask.name.toString())) {
        def yourTaskName = "cleanLibs"
        project.task(yourTaskName) << {
            println "${project.buildDir}/intermediates/pre-dexed/test/debug/"
            delete fileTree(dir: ("${project.buildDir}/intermediates/pre-dexed/test/debug/"))
        }
        theTask.dependsOn(yourTaskName)
        def processTask = "preDexDebugTest"
        project.(yourTaskName.toString()).dependsOn(processTask)
        project.(processTask.toString()).dependsOn("compileDebugTestJava")
    }
}
```

this removes the libs before they are created again, it is slow and ungly, let the libs be created, removes them and creates them again

solution 2:

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { theTask ->
    if("assembleDebugTest".toString().equals(theTask.name.toString())) {
        def processTask = "preDexDebugTest"
        project.(processTask.toString()).enabled = false
    }
}
```

just skip the task that create the first libs, this is way better than the first one

then for both you have to extend

```
android {

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'com/flurry/org/codehaus/jackson/map/VERSION.txt'
        exclude 'com/flurry/org/codehaus/jackson/impl/VERSION.txt'
        exclude 'com/flurry/org/apache/avro/data/Json.avsc'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
}
```

by whatever is twice